# Why ReactJs form's input prefilled with value on load doesn't allow to update it anymore

Tags: reactjs, forms, preload

I am using a form that should allow the user to update the content of the data that has already been saved. Later I load existing data in the form input as follows:-

```
  <input value={profile.displayName} 
  name="displayName" type="text" 
  placeholder="Display Name" 
  /> // it dosn't work  So I tried next

  <input value={profile.displayName} 
  name="displayName" type="text" 
  placeholder="Display Name" 
  onChange={(e) => {setDisplayName(e.target.value )}}/> // Same issue
```

So how do I load the existing data and the data must be editable in the from?

**More code for clarification:-**
I am using hooks like this:-

```
const [profile, setProfile] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {

if (props.match.params.title) {
  setTitle(props.match.params.title);
} else if (props.location.state.title) {
  setTitle(props.location.state.title);
}

if (props.location.state) {
  if (props.location.state.profile) {
    setProfile(props.location.state.profile)
    console.warn("profile: ", props.location.state.profile)
  }
}
```

}

So the profile is coming as props from another component. This part is fine. Also loading data into the form is fine. But after loading data, I can't edit it anymore.

Comment: please share how you initialise profile and code for ```setDisplayName```. profile is an object but setDisplayName takes a string which might overwrite profile object.

Comment: pls, check the updated part for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set initial profile to empty object but assign default value of the input to `profile.displayName` which is `undefined` and react will throw the following warning.

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.*

your initial object should be like

```
const [profile, setProfile] = useState({
  displayName: ""
});
```

Then update the value like

```
<input
  value={profile.displayName}
  name="displayName"
  type="text"
  onChange={e => {
    setProfile({ ...profile, displayName: e.target.value });
  }}
/>
```

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function App() {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState({
    displayName: "",
    gender: "",
    occupation: ""
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setProfile({
      displayName: "StackOverflow",
      gender: "Male",
      occupation: "Software Eng."
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={profile.displayName}
        name="displayName"
        type="text"
        onChange={e => {
          setProfile({ ...profile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        }}
      />
      <input
        value={profile.gender}
        name="gender"
        type="text"
        onChange={e => {
          setProfile({ ...profile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        }}
      />

      <input
        value={profile.occupation}
        name="occupation"
        type="text"
        onChange={e => {
          setProfile({ ...profile, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        }}
      />

      <p>display name: {profile.displayName}</p>
      <p>gender: {profile.gender}</p>
      <p>occupation: {profile.occupation}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: In the profile object, I have few other members such as realName: '',
    birthDate: '',
    height: 0,
    cityLocation: '',
    occupation: '',
    aboutMe: '',
    gender: '',
so how do all of them? setProfile({ ...profile, displayName: e.target.value }); only set displayName.

Comment: I'll update my answer to include the rest of the object.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the reducer to set this kind of complex object? Could pls give tell me how to do it by reducer? I read it online, I have no idea how to do it? I am trying to learn it by doing the reducer.

Comment: Thx, it works nicely. But I would be really interested to see how it can be done by the reducer.

Comment: please read more about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a hook like below

```
const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState('');
```

In useEffect when you set profile also set display name.

```
setDisplayName(props.location.state.profile.displayName)
```

Better destruct the profile in a const

```
const  { profile } = props.location.state;
```

And finally in the input

```
    <input value={displayName} name="displayName" type="text" placeholder="Display Name" onChange={(e) => {setDisplayName(e.target.value )}}/>
```

Comment: I am using hook. But I can't set the initial state as useState(profile.displayName). Coz I get profile later stage. Anyway, I am initializing it empty in the begging. Pls, check the updated text.

Comment: You can still do something like onChange={(e) => {setProfile({ ...profile, displayName: e.target.value} )}}. Although I would recommend keeping displayName in a seperate useState as given in the answer and setting displayName when it is available in useEffect, or moving the input to a new component, with displayName as a prop